# First-Order Plus Dead Time Models python Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, transfer-function

I would like to plot a first order transfer function with time delay in Scipy. To plot the first order transfer function I do:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Kp = 3.0
taup = 2.0

num = [Kp]
den = [taup,1]
sys1 = signal.TransferFunction(num,den)
t1,y1 = signal.step(sys1)

plt.plot(t1,y1,'b--',linewidth=3,label='Transfer Fcn')
plt.show()
```

To plot the first order transfer function with time delay in Matlb I do:

```
num = 3.0;
den = [2.0 1];
P = tf(num,den,'InputDelay',10)
P0 = tf(num,den);
step(P0,'b',P,'r')
```

But how do I plot a first-order transfer function with time dalay in Scipy?

Comment: SciPy doesn't support delays in the LTI models. But a time delay in a time domain simulation is simply an offset in the time vector. So you can plot against `t1+taup`. Alternatively you can replace the delay with its Pade approximation.